# Motivation behind definition of mean deviation

Tags: statistics

So I got to start working on some statistics notes and at first everything seemed intuitive, the concepts were pretty basic. But then they got a little more complicated. So I do know the neat idea behind the mean deviation which is basically that it is a measure of dispersion from the mean. But why it is given by this formula? $$
    \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n |x_i-m(X)|. $$
That is, I want to see a derivation of that formula. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you're missing a square root over the $n$.

Comment: @Bryan The only square root I know is for the standard deviation $$\sigma=\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-m(X))^2.}$$

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I read standard deviation instead of mean deviation.

Comment: I hadn't heard of this before, but the wiki article explains it pretty well I think. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_deviation#Average_absolute_deviation_about_median. The section on minimization helped me the most. Basically, standard deviation corresponds to $L^2$ distance while mean deviation corresponds to $L^1$ distance, if you have some background in real analysis. Why it isn't used so much, I found a good answer here: http://forums.udacity.com/questions/10006597/standard-deviation-vs-mean-absolute-deviation

Comment: I wish I learned real analysis before...

Answer (score 0):

Mean deviation is classically calculated as the arithmetic mean of the absolute values of the differences between observations and the mean or median. This corresponds to the formula that you posted.

Albeit potentially important and rather intuitive, this measure of dispersion is uncommonly used in statistics. This is because the presence of the absolute value would make various types of other statistical calculations more difficult as compared to those obtainable using the SD.